# Unable to display MySQL data in EJS view table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a simple mysql/node.js login app. User login and enters name/pwd. I am able to match user input in mysql table but I can't seem to display the user data from mysql table in an ejs html view table. Browser displays the table row headings ( tags) but not the details ( tags). I get no errors at js console. If you can help me, I will appreciate it.

Below is my client-data.ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>User data page</title>
</head>

<body>    
    <! Display user data from mysql db table havuzs_sakinleri. >

    <h2>Kullanici aidat bilgileri </h2> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Ilk ve soy isim</th>
            <td><%= userdata.isim %></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <th>Blok no</th>
            <td><%= userdata.blokno %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Daire no</th>
            <td><%= userdata.daireno %></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <th>Yil</th>
            <td><%= userdata.yil %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Aylik aidat</th>
            <td><%= userdata.aylik_aidat %></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <th>Toplam odenen TL</th>
            <td><%= userdata.toplam_odenen_tl %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Devredilen TL</th>
            <td><%= userdata.devredilen_tl %></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <th>Aidat bakiye</th>
            <td><%= userdata.aidat_bakiye %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
    <button type=button class="mainpg-btn" >Ana sayfa</button>

</body>
</html>html>
```

Below is the section of my server.js file where mysql query is done and table data is passed to ejs in userdata parm.

```
app.post('/client', (req, res) =>
{  // Make post request to client.html route, to get login data from user. 
    var isim = req.body.isim; 
    var sifre = req.body.sifre;
    
    // Check if name and password inputs exist in database.
    if (isim && sifre) //if user has entered name and password, look for them in the database
        {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM havuzs_sakinleri WHERE isim = ? AND sifre = ?', [isim, 
                  sifre], function(err,rows)  
            { console.log('db query initiated');  
                if (err)  // If error in searching the database, display error message.
                { throw err;
                    console.log('Veri tabani aranirken sorun olustu.'); 
                };
                if (rows.length > 0) // user name and password match db, show user info from 
                                        db.
                { //res.send(results);
                    res.render('client-data', {userdata: rows});
                } 
                else 
                { //if not found in database, display error mesg.
                    console.log('Isim ve sifre veri tabaninda bulunamadi.'); 
                } 
                res.end(); // end response process.  
            });        
        } 
    else //if no user name and pwd entered, display message 
       { console.log('Lutfen isim ve sifre giriniz!');
         res.end(); // end response process.          
       } 
})
```

Comment: `if (rows.length > 0)` — `rows` is an array but inside your EJS you are treating it as a single object.

Comment: That is because there is only going to be 1 entry with that name/pwd. I have also tried iterating in a loop, it made no difference. It looks like the mysql data in is not being passed in userdata parm. I must be missing something or doing something wrong.